# ruby on rails params is nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm having the following code in my view:

```
<%= form_for :command_selected, :method => "get", :url => {:action => "command_domain_selected"} do |f| %>

   <%= f.submit "Make Deployment" %>
<%= f.radio_button :domain, '1dev-den' %> <%= label :domain, '1dev-den'%><br />
   <%= f.radio_button :domain, '2dev-den' %> <%= label :domain, '2dev-den'%><br />
```

When i click on the `submit (make deployment)` button, `parameters` from `submit button` and `radio button` are passed on to the action mentiond in the `form_for` above. But if i do not select any radio button and cilck on submit, it throws the (nil object returned you might be expecting an instance of array) error. However, i want to test if the parameter is nil in my action and redirect to some other view. Below is my code for the action

```
def command_domain_selected
  if(params[:command_selected][:domain].nil?)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html{redirect_to wrong_selection_path}
    end
  else
    @command_selected = params[:commit]      
    @domain_selected = params[:command_selected][:domain]
  end 
end
```

Why is it throwing the nil object error even when im checking it before hand?
Please help

```
Update: Below is the error i'm getting
NoMethodError in AuthorizationController#command_domain_selected 
You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.[]Rails.root: c:/Final/authorize

Parameters: 

{"utf8"=>"✓", "commit"=>"Make Deployment"}
```

Comment: @keymone here is the error NoMethodError in AuthorizationController#command_domain_selected 
You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.[]Rails.root: c:/Final/authorize

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace 
app/controllers/authorization_controller.rb:43:in `command_domain_selected'

Comment: As standard convention, one of the radio button should be selected by default.

Comment: @FirozAnsari That is a good idea. Thank you :). I will do that, but still what might be the reason that is not able to check and redirect? Where am i going wrong?

Comment: May I ask, what does params look like in your controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a guess but could it be that `params[:command_selected]` is nil which you are not checking for.